# Mysql InnoDB database

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam, database-schema

All of my tables are InnoDB but PHPMyAdmin shows that the database is MyIsam: http://img708.imageshack.us/i/201103080940551280x800s.png/
How do I create new MySQL databases using InnoDB?
Running MySQL 5.1, in a Debian Sid box.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it is showing MyISAM because that is your default storage engine on that database, i.e. if you were to create a new table and not specify the engine then it would be MyISAM.

You can change the default storage engine in your my.cnf file:

```
default-storage-engine=INNODB
```

Comment: My /etc/mysql/my.cnf doesn't have this option. Thank you.

Comment: add it then, MySQL's default engine is MyISAM, if you override it then you should see it change

Comment: i've changed it, restarted the database but i still see MyISAM there. Thank you.

Comment: if you select localhost at the top of phpmyadmin and then click the Variables tab, what does it say for the `storage engine` variable?

Comment: can you try using just `storage-engine=INNODB` in your cnf file?

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL Workbench for GUI interface:
http://wb.mysql.com/

You can it directly using SQL also:

```
ALTER TABLE products ENGINE = innodb
```

Comment: But my database stills using MyIsam. Thank you.